# C# return a string from another void

Tags: c#

I'm pretty sure this is an easy one.   I simply want to return a string from another void.

```
public static void LinkWorker(string baseURLString)
{
     // do some stuff here
     HTMLWork(baseURLStringCycle)
     --> this is where i need xstring returned
     foreach(string xyString in xstring.split('\n'))
     {
     }
}

public static void HTMLWork(string baseURLStringCycle)
{
     //do HTML work here
     // create x string
     string xString = ; //the result of the htmlwork
}
```

Comment: I don't think I fully understand the problem. Why don't return a string? Or, you can pass the a string by reference and store the answer there... maybe the limitations are other ones than what I'm seeing...

Comment: It's not that easy to do something impossible! If a method has a return type of `void`, you can't return anything from it. Your code isn't that clear, but it looks like you want to "return" the string in the middle of the method. Perhaps you mean something other than "return"?

Comment: I am just going to repeat pretty much what everyone said.  In both cases HTMLWork and LinkWork both CANNOT return value because they are voids.  If you want to return a string then make HTMLWork return a string.  The code you posted would not compile you cannot have a method instead of a method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not want a `void` method, you want a method returning type `string`.

```
public static string HTMLWork(string baseURLStringCycle) 
{
     //... 
     return xString;
}
```

Comment: And if, for some reason I don't know of, the method must remain void, you can use an `out` parameter: `public static void HTMLWork(string baseURLStringCycle, out xString) { xString = "something"; }`

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to return a value in a void method, since it is a void method. there are 2 ways to achieve the same result though.

1. Use a *global variable* that is both accessible in both methods. Then, set in the *HTMLWork* methods the global variable, and access the same variable in *LinkWorker* method.
2. Pass the variable *by reference* from *LinkWorker* to *HTMLWork*. Since the variable is passed by reference, the changes made in *HTMLWork* will be visible to *LinkWorker*.

Answer (score 3):

You can't return a string from a void function.

```
public static void LinkWorker(string baseURLString)
{

// do some stuff here
string xstring=HTMLWork(baseURLStringCycle)
foreach(string xyString in xstring.split('\n'))
{
}

public static string HTMLWork(string baseURLStringCycle) //use string instead of void
 {
 //do HTML work here
// create x string

string xString = ; //the result of the htmlwork
return xString;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a Void Method, you should use the Out keyword or pass in a Reference.

e.g.

```
public static void HTMLWork(string baseUrlStringCyle, out XResult)
{
  string xString = "result";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you return a string instead of void?

Answer (score 1):

[Anthony's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308616/c-return-a-string-from-another-void/6308640#6308640) is your best bet.

It is also possible to assign a value of a string using an 'out' parameter. But this should not be used when its possible to return directly from the method

eg:

```
public static void HTMLWork(string baseURLStringCycle, out returnString) 
{
returnString  = "returned string";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest, but obviously not the best way would be to make xString a `global` variable.

Other than that unless you have the option of change the HTMLWork method I'm out of options.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to change function signature and keep this void you can use string as a parameter and change this inside the HTMLWork function. C# pass object as reference so the trick is done.