# How to return an out parameter when sending a ref parameter?

Tags: c#, methods, return-type, ref, out

I am sending a ref parameter; want to return an out parameter. Would I also need to create another method along with the ref method?

This is some context to what I am working on: "Create an internal static void method that receives degrees Celsius as a ref parameter and returns degrees Fahrenheit as an out parameter.  There is no input or output in this method."

```
internal static void(ref int c, out int f){
f = c + 32;
return f;
}
```

Comment: I assume this code is for a demonstration of the problem, but note that you're missing some multiplication :)

Comment: How to "return" values from `void` method is asked already. In particular https://stackoverflow.com/a/6308688/477420 shows how to return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things wrong with your method - you are missing a method name, and you are returning a value when your method signature designates a `void` return type.

a third thing, although not a problem, is that there is no point declaring c as a ref parameter, since it is not being altered in your method.

```
internal static void convertCelciusToFahrenheit (ref int c, out int f){
    f = c + 32;
}
```

you also may want to check on your [math to convert celsius to fahrenheit](https://www.thoughtco.com/convert-celsius-to-fahrenheit-609228)

Comment: Why would you say that there's no point in declaring c as a `ref` parameter if it's explicitly requested in the task? " that receives degrees Celsius as a ref parameter"

Comment: i acknowledge that it's a part of the requested task, that's why it is in my solution. i just wanted to point out that it serves no practical purpose in this example.